# Parameters in Behat 3

Tags: php, bdd, behat

I have a website written in PHP with around 40 countries. I started to develop test in Behat v3, with many features. Sometimes, I need to run a feature/suite with a specific country and on a specific server.

For instance, what I have to do is :

```
php bin/behat --suite=mySuite --env=stg --country=US,IT,CA
```

Or something like that. For just retrieve URL by the environment and country passed in parameter. I think it's not possible whit Behat and if not, what kind of tool can I use ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that goes beyond `bin/behat` is Behat specific. So, yes, it's not possible via Behat parameters. This is easily achieved with environment parameters, which you can pass before running the script:

```
ENV="stg" COUNTRY="US,IT,CA" php bin/behat --suite=mySuite
```

In your code you retrieve them from the `$_SERVER` superglobal:

```
$env     = $_SERVER['ENV'];
$country = $_SERVER['COUNTRY'];
```

Comment: Works for the environment, but I have also several Scenario Outlines with countries : my feature need to run for each country I pass in parameter. I need to create a hook or something like that for run the entire scenario for each country ?

Comment: I'm not entirely following and it sounds like a different problem. Ask a new question, I'll have a look a bit later. Make sure to provide the code for that.

Comment: Yep done, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300396/behat-run-again-a-scenario-programmatically.